# Remove comma from last item category list – wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

im using

```
<?php
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
        echo $category->cat_name . ', ';
    }
?>
```

now this obviously outputs a comma at the end of each "category" how would i go about emoving the comma from the last item in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use rtrim:

```
$cats = '';
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    $cats .= $category->cat_name . ', ';
}
echo rtrim($cats, ', ');
```

Comment: Note that the second parameter of `rtrim` is the list of characters to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$categories = array();
foreach(get_the_category() as $category) {
    $categories[] = $category->cat_name;
}

echo implode($categories, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, using the `join` function-

```
echo join(",",array_map(function($category){return $category->cat_name;}, get_the_category()));
```